# UpdatePanel - Dropdownlist in Webpart

Tags: web-part, search, ajax

I want to customize the SearchBoxEx-Control. So I made a Webpart which inherits from SearchBoxEx. In the CreateChildControls I put an updatepanel and two dropdownlists.

Every time I select something in the dropdownbox it makes a postback, that's correct.
But It makes a recreates all controls in updatepanel so that nothing changes. I have to use a normal webpart (no visual webpart because of using searchboxex). The class is   public class ExtendedSearch : SearchBoxEx

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class ExtendedSearch : SearchBoxEx
{
    UpdatePanel mainUpdatePanel;
    UpdateProgress progressControl;
    Button checkTimeButton;
    Label timeDisplayLabel;
    DropDownList category;
    DropDownList subcategory;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        this.DropDownModeEx = DropDownModesEx.ShowDD;

        mainUpdatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
        mainUpdatePanel.ID = "updateAjaxDemoWebPart";
        mainUpdatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
        mainUpdatePanel.RenderMode = UpdatePanelRenderMode.Inline;

        category = new DropDownList();
        category.ID = "dropdownCategory";
        category.Items.Add("Cat 1");
        category.Items.Add("Cat 2");
        category.Items.Add("Cat 3");
        category.CssClass = "ms-sbscopes";
        category.Style["display"] = "inline";
        category.Style["margin-right"] = "10px";
        category.AutoPostBack = true;

        subcategory = new DropDownList();
        category.ID = "dropdownSubCategory";
        subcategory.Items.Add("SubCat 1");
        subcategory.Items.Add("SubCat 2");
        subcategory.Items.Add("SubCat 3");
        subcategory.CssClass = "ms-sbscopes";
        subcategory.Style["display"] = "inline";

        category.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(category_SelectedIndexChanged);

        mainUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(category);
        mainUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(subcategory);
        mainUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger()
        {
            ControlID = category.ID,
            EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged"
        });

        Control scopeDdl = FindControlRecursivly("SBScopesDDL", this);

        if (scopeDdl != null)
        {
            int index = scopeDdl.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(scopeDdl);
            scopeDdl.Parent.Controls.AddAt(index, mainUpdatePanel);
            scopeDdl.Parent.Controls.Remove(scopeDdl);
        }
    }

    private void category_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.subcategory.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }

    private Control FindControlRecursivly(string controlName, Control parentControl)
    {
        foreach (Control control in parentControl.Controls)
        {
            if (control.ID == controlName)
            {
                return control;
            }

            Control subControl = FindControlRecursivly(controlName, control);
            if (subControl != null)
            {
                return subControl;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
  }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it didn't work. When you use an updatepanel standalone in a webpart it works. It only updates the controls which should be updated.

When you inherit from searchboxex and put it there the updatepanel completly refreshes when making an AutoPostback=True.

My Solution was to use JQuery. I attached a Jquery-Function when the control changes its index. Before that I added all subdropdowns to the page and made them hidden with Jquery.

Hope that helps for your own solution.